# How can I enable/add USB OTG support to my rooted stock LG P500?

Tags: usb-on-the-go, lg-optimus-one

I have a rooted LG P500 running stock 2.3.3 with kernel 2.6.35.10.

I would like to use USB OTG features and connect a flash drive to my phone. I have a USB OTG cable that I use with my Nexus 7.  The same cable and same flash drive doesn't work with my phone.

I have tried to install [StickMount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.stickmount), but unfortunately it is not compatible with my phone and so is the [USB Host diagnostics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.usbhostdiagnostics) - however, their [database](http://usbhost.chainfire.eu/)  clearly says P500 does not support USB.

Other than going the route of custom ROM, can some thing be done for enabling USB OTG like patching kernels etc? I am not sure even the previous statement is valid, but just thought of asking as in the [database](http://usbhost.chainfire.eu/) under "Rooted API Claims support" column, the value for LGP500 is said as Yes. And, I checked [this XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1051282&page=4) thread, which also says that the chipset MSM7227 which my phone uses has limited OTG capabilities. Also that thread's title says `Update: Working now`, but I couldn't find anything relevant within its posts. All these just gives me a faint hope.

Update:
My phone's has three files `libra.ko, librasdioif.ko, wireless.ko` in `/system/lib/modules`

Answer (score 2):

In short, MSM7x27 chipsets *have very limited support* for USB OTG, that is despite there is an option in the kernel to build the driver for it, unfortunately it does not work and requires hackery to get it to work 100%!

[image: Zte Blade Kernel configuration]

In reference to this:

> Update: My phone's has three files `libra.ko`, `librasdioif.ko`,
>   `wireless.ko` in /system/lib/modules

Those modules the OP referred to, are tied to the SDIO's chipset support for both the SDCard mechanism and the Wireless. Notably, Atheros's `ar6000` uses the SDIO pins to activate the wireless, and is specific to that driver.

*Offtopic: The SDIO controls the SDCard mechanism, so yeah, it does sound 'cheap' in the sense that using the pins for I/O off the SDCard mechanism, to control the wifi chip...*

As a FYI - Zte Blade and LG-P500 uses the near-identical array of peripherals such as chipset, wifi, but under different manufacturers! Have a mooch around the Modaco thread governing both devices, you might find something in there!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [USB OTG Helper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.shajul.usbotg)? It works with either stock or custom ROM.

*I have not seen the P500 listed as supported, but you could TRY.*

Comment: No. I had already tried this. Since I forgot the app name and its error messasge, I missed to add this info in my question.