# Using external SD Card on LG Optimus

Tags: external-sd

Please tell me how to transfer my data from internal storage to the external SD Card please.... I'm ready to throw this stupid phone out the window.

Comment: Can you please explain what data you want to transfer? Hint: without the device being rooted, access to "internal storage" is pretty restricted, if you refer to that.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of [LG Optimus devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LG_Optimus) and some of them don't have SD Card slot (E973 for example).

If that is your problem then you can try attaching external SD Card reader to your device using [USB OTG to USB adapter](https://www.google.com/search?q=USB+OTG+to+USB+adapter&tbm=isch).

Comment: Lg Optimus series low end phones doesn't have necessary support in kernel for [USB OTG support](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39154/how-can-i-enable-add-usb-otg-support-to-my-rooted-stock-lg-p500). :(

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to transfer data from the internal SDCard to the external, you can do so in several ways:

- use a file explorer directly on the device ([ES File Explorer File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) is a good choice for this)
- attach your device to your computer via USB, and both sdcards should become accessible. Use your favorite file explorer on your PC then to copy/move the files

If, on the other side, you are talking about the internal "phone storage": without root access to your device, your possibilities are pretty limited...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the following:

- You're running the latest Android version (4.1.2).
- You want to transfer media (photos/videos/music).

Most Android devices come with a file manager app installed on the device. Take a look at all your applications (press the grid button on the homescreen) and see if you have one (this can be something such as "My Files", "Files", or "File Manager"). If you happen to have one, open it.

1. Navigate to the media on internal storage.
2. Do a long press on the item/folder that you wish to move.
3. Select the destination on the SD card.